# How to delete a tag from imported XML through VBA (MS Excel)?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am trying to do XML Mapping in my workbook, and I am supposed to work with this XML (given below) which the user would import from here - [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
    <sample>Hi</sample>
<metadata>

<data>
    <main>
    ...
    </main>
</data>
```

XMLs can have only one root tag and the above one has two - `metadata` & `data` - so I must delete one of the root tags, in order to make the XML valid. I would like to delete the `metadata` root tag and keep the data tag. So, after the editing my XML should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <main>
    ...
    </main>
</data>
```

Is it possible to edit an imported XML through Excel VBA?

---

Editing the XML as text won't work for me because I will be sharing the excel file with others and they wouldn't have the capability to edit the XML they are importing. That's why I am looking if I just import the XML, and VBA edits it for me...

Comment: Open the xml as a text file, delete everything thats before `<data>`, save (as another file?) And import using the modified xml? If you want specific help then please edit your question, include your code and explain what is not working with your code.

Comment: Why do you think you need VBA?

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu - the problem is I will be sharing the excel file with other people and they won't be able to do the editing in text. That's why I was thinking if excel itself modifies the XML, the user would just need to import the file, and all the editing would happen backstage.

Comment: @Sonal So does this "excel file" do other things through VBA? How do you expect the user to "import" the file? If your question is just to know whether VBA can do what I said in my previous comment then yes, it should be doable.

Comment: You could instead of sharing the file as standalone, sharing two: one that cleans up the xml file, and your excel.

Comment: @RaymondWu Nope, nothing at the moment is done through VBA. I am figuring out the way to enable the user to import an XML by clicking a custom0-button which runs a macro, and enables the user to select an XML file, and after selecting the XML the macro modifies it accordingly and then automatically maps the worksheet.

Comment: @Sonal Look up on how to do custom ribbonui, application file dialog object, FileSystemObject to modify the file. There are many ways to do it I suppose but i would think it would be easier if you can find a way to get whatever that generates the xml to modify its output

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks, I'll research on those terms . Also, is there any way I could just get the contents of the imported XML file into a string? As I said earlier, I am planning to use a button which would fire a macro, which would let the user select a XML file. After file selection, can VBA store it's contents as in a String variable so I could process it further? Thanks!

Comment: @Sonal Yes you can, open the xml using FSO's `OpenTextFile` method, you can assign the content of the entire file to a string variable using `TextStream`'s `ReadAll` method. From there do your manipulation and use that to either replace the original xml or create a new xml file with the modified xml string.

Comment: @Sonal or, you can open xml file using MSXML2 library which have various functionalities related to xml. I'm not that familiar using that but I'm sure there are ways to do what you need.

Comment: By definition XML is well-informed so should have one root. That markup is not XML and may have been created without valid XML libraries or procedures. Check its source.

Comment: Not too seriously: it seems we get to the *root* of the problem, maybe one should postulate being well-**in**formed as maxim. @Parfait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a top level to create valid XML and then select the node you want.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportXML()

    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, doc As Object
    Dim data As Object, filename As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' select file
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        filename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    ' read file and add top level
    Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpentextFile(filename)
    doc.LoadXML doc.LoadXML Replace(ts.readall, "<metadata>", "<root><metadata>", 1, 1) & "</root>"
    ts.Close
    
    ' import data tag only
    Dim s as string
    Set data = doc.getElementsByTagName("data")(0)
    s = data.XML
    MsgBox s
    'ActiveWorkbook.XmlImportXml data.XML, ImportMap _
    '   :=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1")
    
    ' show maps
    'Dim msg As String, mp As XmlMap
    'For Each mp In ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps
    '    msg = vbLf & mp.Name & " - " & mp.RootElementName
    'Next
    'MsgBox "XML Maps" & msg
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @CDP1802! Thanks for your wonderful answer :) Instead of mapping, will it be possible to get the contents of the `data` tag from the fetched XML into a String variable and then just display it (using msgbox etc.)? Kindof struggling to achieve this... Kindly guide. :)

Comment: Thanks @CDP1802 - for some reason, I am getting this error -  `runtime error '91' : Object variable or with block variable not set`, and `MsgBox data.XML` is being highlighted - I am not sure what this means; kindly guide (BTW I exactly copied your code and ran it, no changes made) Thanks!

Comment: @CDP1802 This is the xml I am using : `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
    <sample>Hi</sample>
<metadata>

<data>
    <main>Into Data Now</main>
</data>` --- Is there something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Sonal You have 2 opening `<metadata>` tags , is the 2nd one not `</metadata>` ? You didn't show `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in your question.

Comment: @CDP1802 Sorry - I fixed it (I forgot to add the / in closing metadata tag), now it's `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
<sample>Hi</sample>
</metadata>

<data>
<main>Into Data Now</main>
</data>`. But the runtime error still persists. Kindly guide.. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @CDP1802 - Works a treat now :) Thanks again!